# Windows RStudio Git: Directory name is invalid

Tags: windows, git, rstudio

I have Git-Version control on a folder on my computer, I create a RStudio-project based on that folder, and when entering RStudio and selecting the `Git` tab on the top right part of the window, I get an endlessly looping symbol. If I try to click `Diff` or `Commit` or any other button, I get the following message*

> Directory name is invalid

In the project options > Git/SVN, I have `Git` selected and my origin is `None` and I suspect that the problem comes from there. FYI: I cannot change the content of the origin field by hand.

**NB:** The Git project is intended as a local version control, not for upload / sharing.

*surprisingly the message is in German, even though my RStudio language is English, and my Git language is English, so this above is a translation.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I use localised (Hungarian) windows at the lab. If the path to the project folder contains accented characters the above mentioned message appears. If the accented characters in folder-names are changed to non-accented everything works nicely.